# Cannot connect DDMS to HTC device

Tags: android, ddms

Cannot debug on device using android plugin for eclipse.

Once I push the debug button, DDMS starts looping with this message:

```
[2011-11-21 XX:41:05 - DeviceMonitor]Sending Tracking request failed!
[2011-11-21 XX:41:05 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:EOF
```

Closed eclipse and restarted without firewall, no luck.
Tested "adb devices" in command line, the connected device is shown.
Drivers are installed.
Debug mode is enabled.
Debuggable set to true in manifest.

UPDATE:
Tried starting ddms.bat from android tools folder, same behaviour.
Seems that there are other people having trouble with this, and most of them are reporting this as an issue with HTC drivers. Despite having updated to the most recent version, it still doesn't work.

Comment: which Platform you are using, Windows or Ubuntu ?

Comment: @Pawan Windows XP x32. Now you mention it, do I have to install additional drivers?

Comment: Plz check that your device manager, does not contain any warning or error in  Yellow color, also update your sdk tools etc..

Answer (score 2):

I regularly have this same problem with DDMS and my DroidX as of ADT 15.  Killing and restarting adb *alone* does not fix my problem either.

The symptom of my issue is similar to yours: I see 10 or 15 iterations of my device in the devices list all of which say they are not connected or something to that effect.

My procedure to fix it:

1. Disconnect the device from USB.
2. Run `adb kill-server` on the command line.
3. Run `adb start-server` on the command line.  Wait for the daemon to start.
4. Reconnect the device.

Having reconnected the device, you should be able to run `adb devices` and see only one device in the results. You should be good to go!

Comment: Yes, killing adb solved the multiple devices listed in `adb devices`. However, I only had this problem after reinstalling driver. After first kill, every `adb devices` output lists only one. Tried with every possible combination of killing adb + unpluging + restarting eclipse with no success by the moment. I'm seriously thinking that this is a problem of HTC not solving this issue with the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7

All you need is an upgrade to the drivers of your device on your machine.
Try out something like :

> To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for the first time:
>
> - Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
> - Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
> - Select Devices in the left pane.
> - Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
> - Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
> - Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
> - Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
> - Click Next to install the driver. Or, to upgrade an existing Android USB driver on Windows 7 with the new driver:
>
> Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
>   - Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
>   - Select Device Manager in the left pane of the Computer Management window.
>   - Locate and expand Android Phone in the right pane.
>   - Right-click Android Composite ADB Interface and select Update Driver. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
>   - Select Install from a list or specific location and click Next.
>   - Select Search for the best driver in these locations; un-check Search removable media; and check Include this location in the search.
>   - Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
>   - Click Next to upgrade the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Close eclipse, stop adb process from command line with `adb kill-server`, relaunch your eclipse project.

Comment: Doesn't work. Now I'm puzzled about why it starts looping when I start eclipse, instead of when I try to debug it.

Comment: Try reinstalling driver. I had weird problems I couldn't fix and reinstalling helped me in the past. If it doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled driver from official site. At first, adb came up with a weird output showing multiple devices, everyone with the same ID, all offline except the last. Killed adb server and restarted, and now only shows one device. Then relaunched eclipse project, and same loop again. I edited my question to point that this is not an eclipse error or a plugin error, but a DDMS issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer side not working as others suggested (disconnect the device, kill adb close eclipse etc...) try to set the device debugging mode to off settings->applications->development->USB debugging
after a second or two turn it back on, thats usually do the trick for me...

Comment: Doesn't work. But thanks to you I remembered to turn debug mode off after testing (it is not a good idea on a rooted device XD ).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with HTC One and Windows 7.  My device shows in Device Manager as Portable Devices > HTC One.  I could access it with Explorer and see files but not make an ADB connection.

The way I resolved this was, Device Manager > Right Click my device > Properties > Driver tab > Update Driver > "Browse my computer for driver software" > "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer" (at bottom of dialog) ...

There are two choices:

MTP USB Device
USB Composite Device

Select USB Composite Device and click Next, after a while the driver was installed and the device showed up in DDMS, I didn't even need to restart ADB.

Note that I have HTC Sync Manager software installed and updated but not running, and developer mode and USB debugging are turned on in my HTC One.

Great phone!  Pain to connect :)

[image: Here is a picture of the driver selection screen where you can choose USB Composite Device]